# Null Account in insert procedure in Contact

Tags: account, contact, standard-objects, null

I'm trying to add an Account id to Contact but when I do the insert and than I check the Contact just created it appear null.

I'm using the following code:

```
Account Acc = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'pierfrancoForte' LIMIT 1];

Contact c = new Contact(FirstName ='GianPoldo', LastName='Test');
c.Account = Acc;
insert c;
```

I've also checked the Acc object by debug function and it is not null,
but when i check the record on the db it is null:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below code

```
Account Acc = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'pierfrancoForte' LIMIT 1];

Contact c = new Contact(FirstName ='GianPoldo', LastName='Test');
c.AccountId = Acc.Id;
insert c;
```

Comment: Thanks, now it fill the field 
but if I can ask you more for the future,
Where can I read this field's name?
if I go on the field's detail from setup i can see these informations  

'Field Information
Field Label Account Name Field Name Account
Data Type Lookup(Account) Child Relationship Name Contacts'

but I cannot see AccountId anywhere, how did you knew it?

Again Thanks! Your answer was very helpful

Comment: The best way to check the API Name of standard objects/fields is either Force.com IDE or Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link the Contact to the Account using the `AccountId` field.
Like this:

```
Account Acc = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'pierfrancoForte' LIMIT 1];

Contact c = new Contact(FirstName ='GianPoldo', LastName='Test');
c.AccountId = Acc.Id;
insert c;
```